# How to display Ubercart product attributes in columns

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

Has anyone been able to configure a custom product page so that the attributes are displayed across several columns (as checkboxes) instead of a massive one-row list? I have two attributes for a product that have at least fifty options (one for each state) and to have this as a long list is unwieldy.

Any suggestions?